# Usage of “jealous of”

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context

Stephen Fry in his book Heroes describes how Gigantomachy started, by stating that Alcyoneus stole the cattle from Helios.
The passage goes as follows:

> *“The sun god Helios was **jealous of** his fine herd of cattle. Their theft by the giant Alcyoneus proved the final provocation...”*

Which, as I understand it, implies that Helious was widely known for his cattle, thus OTHERS were *jealous of* SAID CATTLE.
That’s where the confusion lies, because in the sentence above it is worded as if Helios himself was jealous of his own cattle.

I cannot seem to find a similar example of this usage of *jealous*, so maybe I’m just understanding it wrong?
Would appreciate an explanation for this!

Comment: "I am jealous of my wife" would usually mean that she got the last piece of cake that I wanted.  But the sentence might (rarely) be used in a different sense, to mean that I am angered when other men pay too much attention to her.   Your quote appears to be using "jealous" in this latter sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From AHD:

> 4. Vigilant in guarding something: We are jealous of our good name.

This is the use in your quotation. I am not sure it would be widely understood today.

https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=jealous

The entry also has a usage note on envious vs. jealous.

Answer (score 0):

Chambers defines **jealous** thus: suspicious of, or upset or angered by,  rivalry; envious; solicitous, anxiously heedful; mistrustfully vigilant; unable to tolerate faithlessness, or the thought of it.

It might well be that others *envied* Helios for his herds of cattle. If Helios knew of this and saw those others as rivals, we have Helios's jealousy in the first and third senses given above. To describe the others as jealous is to use the second sense above, but the trouble with this is that it uses "jealous" in an ambiguous way and might mislead people as to who had the cattle and who felt what emotion.